# How do I display the current disk IO queue length on Linux?

Tags: linux, io, kernel, block, scheduler

I am working on a new IO scheduler for the Linux Kernel. I am trying to see if anyone knows of a tool that prints out total number of outstanding IO requests (Disk IO queue) in Linux?

I would be working from a terminal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 43):

Forgive the massive necro here. You actually want `iostat -x` which will display the extended stats for the device in question since last iostat was run. If you wish to monitor the queue in realtime you want `iostat -xt 1` (or `iostat -xmt 1` to show details in megabytes).

You can see the average queue size in the `aqu-sz` column (in previous versions `avgqu-sz`).

Consider the following example output from `iostat -xmt 1` which shows a full IO queue (max queue length is 128 for this device) and a saturated disk during a benchmark.

```
18/05/15 00:41:05
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    6.02    0.00   93.98

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    1.00 1308.00     0.00   163.50   255.81   133.30  101.15   0.76 100.00
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dmitry@pro:~$ iostat 
          disk0       cpu     load average
    KB/t tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
   50.70  34  1.70   4  3 93  1.83 1.65 1.70
dmitry@pro:~$
```

> DESCRIPTION
>        Iostat displays kernel I/O statistics on terminal, device and cpu opera-
>        tions.  The first statistics that are printed are averaged over the sys-
>        tem uptime.  To get information about the current activity, a suitable
>        wait time should be specified, so that the subsequent sets of printed
>        statistics will be averaged over that time.

Comment: I learned about this file "/proc/diskstats", if I cat that file, my SSD disk line looks as such:

16 sdb 419177 2902 4840388 1711380 2733730 11581604 199209864 100752396 0 796116 102463264

Based on linux doc, the ninth field is my queue length --> so "0" in my case. Do you think this is actually the disk IO queue length?

documentation for this file can be found at: http://www.unix.com/linux/157963-how-calculate-disk-queue-length-disk-busy-time.html

Comment: On clean installation run apt-get install sysstat to get the iostat command.