# Simple Oracle query is extremely slow the first time, cannot control the database?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Really I'm stuck with this because the database is not of mine, out of my control. I can build a similar database to test in my environment but of course should not modify anything on that database. Now what I can do to improve this is try to change the query.

But even when it's just simple like this, it takes about *20* seconds the first time?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM SomeTableOf_500K_Rows
```

Whereas for a similar SQL Server database (with that same table in schema and size), it takes just 1 second the first time, the next times it reports `00:00:00`

My customers want it faster but really it's limited by their database/server.

I don't know much about how Oracle server works, the test database is right in the same local network, there should not be any reason involving networking speed here.

I've also tried this but still the same problem:

```
SELECT /*+ NOCACHE */ count(*) FROM SomeTableOf_500K_Rows
```

I want Oracle server to somehow remove all unnecessary jobs while performing such a simple query the first time so that it works just as fast as the SQL Server (at least a bit around that execution time).

**Update**:
Today I get back to my environment and done some more tests, it's strange that even for another table of just 74 rows, the `select count(*) from that_table` still takes about 13-20 seconds the first time? It is much slower than `select * from that_table`, really strange.

**UPDATE with tracing info**:
By using `tkprof` and some statement to enable tracing for the current session, I  could obtain the trace-file, analyzed it into an output text file (using `tkprof`). Really the result shows me nothing new, just a black-box of table-access-full consuming ***28 seconds*** to load just ***74*** rows (of course for the first time). The *black-box* I mean looks like this:

---

```
SQL ID: 9jpk7931105mh Plan Hash: 1282975746

select * 
from
 TestTable


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.01       0.01          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        1      2.92      28.96       7427       7436          0          74
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        3      2.93      28.97       7427       7436          0          74

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 92  
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
        74         74         74  TABLE ACCESS FULL TestTable (cr=7436 pr=7427 pw=0 time=2017 us starts=73 cost=2017 size=6734 card=74)
```

---

The total time to run the test query is about ***29.651*** seconds, as you can see the black-box above consumes almost the time (***28.97*** seconds).

If possible please take a look at the full output file (after analyzing) here https://pastebin.com/Euv4mseu

Also note that for each test, I always run the following statements to clear cache, so that the query will not be affected by caching:

```
alter system flush BUFFER_CACHE;
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

Comment: How much does `select count(*) from dual` take?

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy sorry that I'm not in my setup environment now, so I cannot answer that question to you now, the next Monday would be possible to do this. If possible please give me some hints on why that may matter here, thanks.

Comment: Dual is an Oracle system table always having 1 record and should take fraction of a second to execute. If it takes longer then the issue is the call to the db and not thedb

Comment: @xQbert thank you for your helpful info, but if in case that `select from dual` is also slow, how could I solve this? in fact the real data is much larger and I have more complex query to execute, I've also tried running that in the customer's environment and it took 4 minutes the first time, so it's really unacceptable. The customer's database does not have index (for quick joining) but even with that condition, the query should take just about 15-20 seconds, not up to 4 minutes.

Comment: When you say `SELECT * FROM DUAL` is slow, how long does it take? And...what host OS is being used? Windows? Linux? Other Unix-esque flavor? ???

Comment: @BobJarvis sorry that is just my assumption (please see my first comment to Maxim Balaganskiy), I don't know if it is slow or fast, how much time it may take now. All those question of yours can just be answered when I get in my setup environment on the next Monday.

Comment: You might have a look at [tracing a session](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof), or else [SQL Monitor](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/real-time-database-operation-monitoring-12cr1), [ADDM](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/automatic-database-diagnostic-monitor-10g) or [ASH](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/active-session-history) (if licensed).

Comment: You say it takes 20 seconds to run the "first time". What about subsequent times? The rest of my comment I'll put forward as an answer.

Comment: Obviously Oracle is not inherently slower than SQL Server: otherwise it would not be the database behemoth it is. So your customer's environment has some peculiarity which requires hands-on diagnosis.  There really is not much we can do to help you without access to the system. It literally could be anything: undersized server, shoddy interconnects, poorly configured SAN. not enough RAM, too few CPUs, corrupt disc, dodgy network. And that's before we consider the details of your application code.

Comment: @TenG the next times are all fast, just the first time (after each running clear-cache queries like: 'alter system flush...')

Comment: I've tried running the `select count(*) from dual` and it's fast even on the first time.

Comment: @APC actually I'm not so sure about the customer's environment, what similar to my setup environment is both run the same queries slowly the first time. So at first all I have to do here is try running the query fast in my environment and then re-try that in the customer's environment to see if it works. I've commented a lot to all the answers below and I think there is one thing I've tried showing that it should not be the hardware problem (querying on a copied table with all indexes removed is really fast as expected).

Comment: the plan shows physical I/O (disk) - as expected after the flushing of the shared pool. But they seem to be extremely slow. You could take a look at `V$FILESTAT` to see, if the `AVGIOTIM` is extremely high for the corresponding data file - or if this is a common effect in the system. The information in `V$EVENT_HISTOGRAM` could tell you, if there are many extremely slow events for `db file scattered read` (the standard event for FULL TABLE SCANs). But this will not make the access faster...

Comment: Have you checked memory usage? If the database is regularly pushed out of memory, it can result in slowness. My production server (SQL Server) had ran into this because two instances were competing for physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the bottleneck is the file system, or a high water mark.

- Check the disk queue length, it should be below 5 expect for some peaks.
  Windows: Use the Process Monitor and click on Resources to display the disk Queue length.
  Linux: See [Disk queue length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613550/how-do-i-display-the-current-disk-io-queue-length-on-linux)
- Check the high water mark of the table.
  High water marks occur if the table was much larger in the past.
  See: [Query HWM (High Water Mark)](https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=monitoring&file=high_water_mark.sql)
- Alternative Check
  Create a copy of the table and try to query it.
  The copy will not have a high water mark.

  CREATE TABLE SomeTableOf_500K_Rows_Tst AS SELECT * FROM SomeTableOf_500K_Rows;
  SELECT count(*) FROM SomeTableOf_500K_Rows_Tst;

Comment: How to chek if h the disk queu and as for the water marke the soultion is reorgenjze the table however add the query that identfy high water mark

Comment: I'm not so sure what High Water Mark can matter in my specific scenario, but by creating a copy table, the query runs fast on that copy table. The only obvious difference I've found here between the 2 tables is the original one has a ***composite primary key of 5 columns***, while the copied one does not have any index or primary key.

Comment: A count(*) without any where condition ends in a full table scan, the composite index does not care here. And if the table was large once, the complete table including the empty block is scanned. Removing a high water mark is not that easy in a productive environment, and the question is how to prevent that it occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

do you actually need the exact number? Sometimes the table statistics from user_tables.num_rows are good enough (if they have been gathered recently). For Oracle versions >= 12 another option could be the function approx_count (based on an hyperloglog strategy), which returns a almost exact result very fast.

To find out, why your query takes so much time, you would have to take a look at an execution plan (if possible taken from memory via dbms_xplan.display_cursor): maybe the access is not efficient (maybe as a result of misleading statistics). Or the segments involved in the plan (table or index) are bigger than they should be and could be reorganized/rebuild.

Comment: Regardless of whether the OP needs a precise number there must be something wrong if it takes **20 seconds** to count **500,000 rows**.

Comment: assuming that the number and size of columns is not very unusual - I would not disagree

Comment: in fact the `select count(*) from ...` is just a simple query to test this strange thing, I don't need to get any count here (in the actual code). As per my comment to TenG, running `ANALYZE INDEX` first makes `select count(*) from ...` run normally BUT the `ANALYZE INDEX ...` itself takes almost the same time as the `select count(*) from ...` run before (the first time). So actually that can reveal something wrong but not solve this issue.

Comment: @APC yes looks like there is something wrong here that may  not even involve the number of fetched rows, because I've tried with another table which has only `74 rows` but it still runs slowly in a strange way (varied from 13-20 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Does it always take 20 seconds or just at the first run?

The following are just some **basic** checks.

If you could try `SET AUTOTRACE ON`, or use SQL Developer to get an explain then run the query do you see a `INDEX SCAN` or `FULL TABLE SCAN`?

If FTS, then look at the indexes in the table :

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'THE_TABLE';
```

If there are no indexes ... try creating an index.

If there are indexes present, are any of them marked as not VALID?

If all are valid, try the query but add a hint to use one of the indexes on the table (ideally the primary key one if present).

If even with the index (confirm that this is being used in the explain plan) it doesn't run quickly, and the index is an existing one (not one you freshly built), try

```
ANALYSE INDEX THE_INDEX VALIDATE STRUCTURE;
```

Then retry the query.

If still no better, try the **nuclear** option:

```
ALTER INDEX THE_INDEX REBUILD;
```

If still no better, then you are probably at a point where you need a deep dive into the Oracle witchcraft.

At that point you will start to need to look at session waits etc.

Comment: the query runs slowly just on the first time, the next times are fast. It has a composite primary key of multiple columns (5 columns). It's strange that even for another table of just 74 rows, the `select count(*) from ...` also takes about 13-20 seconds? Really strange.

Comment: there is just 1 primary key index (as I said above), and after running the `ANALYZE INDEX` for that index the `select count(*) from ...` ***runs fast*** even for the first time. But the `ANALYZE INDEX` run before took fairly much time (***almost equal to*** the time running the `select count(*) from ...` first).

Comment: @Hopeless - it's not clear from your last comment above whether the proble is resolved, and if so, whether it was the INDEX REBUILD or ANALYZE INDEX that helped.

Comment: The problem has not been solved yet, the `ANALYZE INDEX` makes the following `SELECT` faster (as normal) but as I said the `ANALYZE INDEX` itself consumes an equivalent amount of time as the `SELECT` alone. So after clearing cache, `ANALYZE INDEX` still consumes much time. It may relate to the composite indexes here, actually a table without any index can be queried fast even for the first time. Really I cannot think of any reason why the Oracle server must consume so much time for querying on indexed table the first time. I thought that indexed table would slow down only the UPDATE/INSERT.

Comment: by the way the table without indexing I mentioned above is created by cloning an existing table (using AS SELECT ...). So maybe it's created without any buffer or cache setting and that may be the cause (not the composite key) making the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on sqltrace and run tkprof on the trace file and see what your wait events are.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof

Comment: this looks like some kind of advanced diagnosing and fairly promising (I've tried playing with 'Explain Plan' but what it shown is just normal). However I've just stopped at generating the trace file, the next to do is to analyze that file, by rawly reading that file is not a good way, the tool `tkprof` is something fairly hidden and hard to download/install at least in Windows OS, so if possible please let me know where and how I can install that hidden tool. Why does the SQL Developer not integrate with that tool?

Comment: Just tried out the `tkprof` and really it does not show anything deep inside the cause of much time consuming. I've just looked at the `elapsed` column for all tables (in the output analyzed file) and there is just 1 table showing almost time consumed there which is just a table-access-full (but all data it has is just ***74*** rows while the time consumed is up to ~28 seconds). That really points me to a black-box (the table access full) without any detailed insight on what it did for such a long time.

Comment: If possible, please spend sometime overlooking the analysis result here https://pastebin.com/Euv4mseu

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the parallel option is activated on your table. If yes switch it off

alter table YourTable noparallel ;